# Creating constant image of various values in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, imagery

For general code debugging, I would like to run my code on a much smaller image that kind of mimics the real image to be processed. The reasons are two folds: one is to save computational time/resources during the debugging process. The other is to better control the values that I can plug in for the debugging purposes. As such, is there a way to create a small (e.g. 10 pixel by 10 pixel) image with pre-stocked values, for example 100 at pixel coordinate (1, 1), value 200 at pixel coordinate (1, 2) etc. ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131212/discussion-on-question-by-hui-creating-constant-image-of-various-values-in-googl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution that comes to mind is:

1. Produce an image with value `1` at the desired origin coordinates using `Image.paint()`.
2. Use `Image.convolve()` to expand that point into the desired pattern of constants.

```js
// Input array
var array = ee.Array([
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0.5], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0.5, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
]);

// Convert to image centered on originPoint
var patternImage =
  ee.Image.constant(0)
    .paint(originPoint, 1)
    .convolve(ee.Kernel.fixed({weights: array.toList() }));

Map.addLayer(patternImage);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d151b9f11bb3f87ded74c4ac4937e9e4

That's assuming you have an array that's a "image" of pixel values. If your array has coordinate columns and value columns, instead, then the best option would be to convert the array to a `FeatureCollection` (with the desired value as a property) and use `Image.paint()` to draw that.

Comment: 1.) My array is an "image" of the the pixel values. 2) I am not sure the code in your answer achieves the goal of my question: the convolve operation is between each pixel in the source image and the array. What I want as a result is an image that looks just like the array.

Comment: @Hui The idea is that the source image for convolution has _exactly one nonzero pixel_, at the `originPoint`, so it produces a copy of the kernel as the output image.

Comment: I see your point. Thank you for your help!